# Двойной пост запрос или как это сделали?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, веб-программирование

Всём привет. 
Есть сайт на котором хранятся  виртуальные финансы для сайта и система зачисления,  вывода,  перевода между пользователями и т. д. 
Ближе к теме,  один человек смог каким-то образом вывести сумму два раза одну и ту же, все это дело произошло в один момент, дата двух транзакций одинаковая, сумма первой транзакции полная стоимость его финансов на сайте,  а вторая получается транзакция которая создавалась она не должна была создаться так как сумма на счету 0.
Все защиты от F5 и тому подобное присутствуют. 
Вопрос: как это сделали?

Само решение я так понимаю кроется в mysql транзакциях и как этим пользоваться я примерно понимаю меня больше интересует как такое можно сделать чтоб бы больше понимать.

Вот кусок кода который отвечает за создание заявки:

```
$paySys = Paymsys::findByName($this->tasys_in, $this->amount_in)->setPersent(true);

    if ($paySys->sysAbbr == null) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "<div class=\"alert alert-danger text-center\">Направильное имя системы</div>");
        return false;
    }

    $this->amount_in_origin = $paySys->sum;
    $this->tasys_in = $paySys->sys;
    $this->user_real_sum = UserMoney::getSum($paySys->sysAbbr);
    $money = OperationsMoney::start($paySys)->moneyDeduct();

    if (!$money->save()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('alert', $money->getError() . "&nbsp" . $money->getSum() . '&nbsp' . $paySys->sysAbbr);

        return false;
    }
```

Дата хранится в обычном формате 2016-08-22 00:21:51

Comment: как ведет себя бэк если ему послать одновременно 2 одинаковых запроса на эту операцию?

Comment: Можно поконкретней пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрим два параллельных потока (1) и (2)

1. Исходный остаток: 10
2. (1) Запрос на снятие 8
3. (2) Запрос на снятие 7
4. (1) Сумма не превышает 10. Снимаем. В итоге получим 10 - 8 = 2
5. (2) Сумма не превышает 10. Снимаем. В итоге получим 10 - 7 = 3
6. (1) Запишем 2 в базу
7. (2) запишем 3 в базу
8. Итог: сняли 8 + 7 = 15, текущий остаток 3

Способ решения: на 4 этапе блокировать таблицу. Тогда получим такую картину:

1. Исходный остаток: 10
2. (1) Запрос на снятие 8
3. (2) Запрос на снятие 7
4. (1) Заблокировали запись. Сумма не превышает 10. Снимаем. В итоге получим 10 - 8 = 2
5. (2) Попытались заблокировать запись. Она уже заблокирована. Ждем
6. (1) Запишем 2 в базу
7. (1) Разблокировали запись
8. (2) Заблокировали запись. Сумма превышает 2. Отлуп
9. (2) Разблокировали запись
10. Итог: сняли 8, текущий остаток 2

В коде это будет выглядеть так

```php
mysqli_autocommit(false);
$res = mysqli_query("SELECT money FROM my_table WHERE user_id = $id LOCK FOR UPDATE");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
mysqli_free_result($res)
if ($row[0] >= $val)
  mysqli_query("UPDATE my_table SET money = GREATEST(money - $val, 0) WHERE user_id = $id");
else
  echo "Облом!";
mysqli_commit();
```

Параметры и обработку ошибок добавить по вкусу

Comment: Получается я все правильно думаю, нужно использовать транзакции?

Comment: @KoVadim Мешает. `FOR UPDATES`

Comment: @Ricco381 Да. Они именно для этого и предназначены

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Answer (score 0):

> дата двух транзакций одинаковая

На сколько точная дата? `mysql` для `timestamp` и `datetime` хранит как самую малую единицу всего лишь секунду. Одна секунда - это очень много времени. За такое время даже человек может умудриться сделать несколько запросов. А автоматика с лёгкостью.

Классический `race condition` в вашем коде. Надо внимательно смотреть код и думать, что может пойти не так при конкурентном доступе.

СУБД вполне неплохое место для сериализации транзакции. Но про конкурентный доступ надо будет всё равно думать. Просто сказать `begin/commit` недостаточно.

> Все защиты от F5 и тому подобное присутствуют

Очевидный вывод - эти проверки были реализованы некорректно или только для частных случаев.

Без кода сказать ничего нельзя, кроме как "race condition". С кодом - скорей всего его довольно много и просто так вычитывать желающих может не найтись.

Comment: Дата хранится в обычном формате 2016-08-22 00:21:51

Comment: Добавил код, про **race condition** почитал но не понял

Answer (score 0):

Внедрение транзакций в готовый код может оказаться очень сложным делом.
Если у вас немного таких критических мест, то можно использовать семафоры http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.sem.php Или организовать подобное на memcache http://php.net/manual/ru/memcached.add.php